# Can I get sued by a company after winning a chargeback?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, law, contracts, chargeback

I have a problem with a company that has delivered a service that it considers to be completed, even though it has failed to comply with the contract.

I have evidence to justify these failures and would like to possibly open a dispute for a chargeback as the transaction has been paid by credit card.
However, I want to make sure of several things before taking these steps.

The contract is governed by United States law and states the following:

1. "Sanctions and termination [...] The parties have no right to unilateral termination. This rule is justified by the principle of the binding nature of the contract."
2. "Jurisdiction [...] All disputes arising out of or in connection with this contract shall be finally settled in accordance with the Rules of Conciliation and Arbitration of the International Chamber of Commerce without recourse to the ordinary courts by one or more arbitrators appointed in accordance with those rules, whose award shall be binding. The arbitral tribunal shall be the judge of its own jurisdiction and of the validity of the arbitration agreement."

Under these notations, and in the event the chargeback is successful, can the provider then sue me to recover the funds or am I protected by law having won the chargeback proceeding?

For now the service provider scammed us and I want to protect myself in the event that the chargeback is decided on my side be cause I think he would use any means at his disposal to pressure me.

Comment: You can get sued by anyone for anything at any time. The better question to ask would be who would win the lawsuit. Which is a question you should ask a real lawyer, and not anonymous know-it-alls on the Internet like me.

Comment: Arbitration is a legitimate venue in the US for resolving contract disputes.  But "Rules of the International Chamber of Commerce" sounds bogus -- arbitration in the US has to apply US law.

Comment: @BenVoigt I absolutely do not know how arbitration works and who I should be in touch with to deal with it. However I agree it seems to be better than opening a dispute that can cause me troubles. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @BenVoigt That wording seems to be a mildly edited version of the [Standard ICC Arbitration Clause](https://iccwbo.org/news-publications/arbitration-adr-rules-and-tools/standard-icc-arbitration-clauses-english-version/), so it's definitely not something just made up on the spot by the service provider. It's fairly likely that at least one real lawyer approved it.

Comment: @jawpotato: You would still want to let your bank know, now, that the particular charge is being disputed and you are going to pursue arbitration.  That way they can stop the merchant from disappearing with the money.  But I think it's in your interest to do the chargeback and make them chase you.

Comment: You also want to check whether the amount disputed is within the limits for "Small Claims Court".  Arbitration agreements often still allow claims brought in Small Claims Court, it might even be a law that they can't exclude it.

Answer (score 6):

They can't sue you because of the arbitration clause. But they can demand to bring the case to an arbitration tribunal. Because in their opinion, they fulfilled their side of the contract but you didn't fulfill yours (paying them for it).

Then, at that tribunal, you can make your arguments. They will argue that they fulfilled the contract. You will argue that they didn't. The arbitrator(s) will then either decide that you were in your right to withhold payment, that you should have paid in full, or that the service provider is at least entitled to a partial payment for partial work.

Which outcome is the most likely? That's a question you should ask a real lawyer, not anonymous strangers on the Internet.

Oh, and because this is arbitration and not a real court case, any legal fees will probably be paid by the parties themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'm actually looking for leads before seeing a lawyer if needed.

I'm french and the merchant is also french but has its company in US and US law applies. I obviously cannot go to a tribunal, plus I don't need as the contract states any disputes need to be treated without recourse to the ordinary courts but by one or more arbitrators. 

The fact here is that I absolutely don't know how it works and who I should be contacting for that matter, which seems to be better than opening a dispute that can cause me troubles.

Comment: It's not obvious that US law applies. EU consumer protection rules generally target anyone marketing towards Europeans, and in for instance Norway a arbitration clause is not binding for a consumer, if entered into *before* the conflict (Voldgiftsloven §11)

Comment: To add to this, if the contract says that disputes will be handled via arbitration and you handle this dispute via chargeback, then you risk being found in breach of contract even if the job wasn't actually completed (I suppose you'd *both* be in breach). The safest course is to follow whatever dispute procedures you agreed to in the contract. Don't give them any ammo to use against you.

Comment: @jawpotato _"I'm french and the merchant is also french"_ is extremely important and must be edited into the question for any answer to make sense.